# PHP script for PIVOT in SQL

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pivot

I have a View **Emp_PRJ_Art** in my SQL Server as below.

```
UsedArticleNo | EmpName | Project | EmpRol  
PART0001    |    Tintin | PRJ1    |   PL  
PART0002    |   Haddok  | PRJ2    |   TL  
PART0003    |   Poppey  | PRJ3    |   GET  
PART0004    |   Archie  | PRJ4    |   PM  
PART0005    |   Tintin  | PRJ1    |   PL  
PART0006    |   Archie  | PRJ4    |   PM  
PART0007    |   Tintin  | PRJ3    |   PL  
PART0008    |   Haddok  | PRJ3    |   TL  
PART0009    |   Poppey  | PRJ1    |   GET
```

I want to get a result like this. The numbers under PRJ columns are total number of Article used by the employee for that particular Project.

```
EmpName |PRJ1 | PRJ2 |  PRJ3 | PRJ4 |  EmpRol  
Archie  | 0   |  0   |   0   |  2   |  PM  
Haddok  | 0   |  1   |   1   |  0   |  TL  
Poppey  | 1   |  0   |   1   |  0   |  GET  
Tintin  | 2   |  0   |   1   |  0   |  PL
```

I used the SQL query like this and getting the result as required.

```
SELECT *   
FROM ( SELECT EmpName, UsedArticleNo, Project  
        FROM Emp_PRJ_Art)  
PIVOT(COUNT(UsedArticleNo) FOR (Project) IN ('PRJ1','PRJ2','PRJ3',’PRJ4’))  
ORDER BY EmpName;
```

Now my problem is, I am not able to use PHP to get this query run and finally display the same table as webpage, as I am getting in SQL Developer Console. Below is the PHP code not working.

```
    <?php

$backcol="bgcolor=#9fffa1"; // Light Green
$colgreen1="bgcolor=#5EE060"; // Light Green

$maxitems=1000; // Maximum items found to display

$s=" <small> ";

$user='odbc';
$pass='abcd';
$sid ='server1.myComp.com';

$adr = "http://server1/WebEditor";

$conn = oci_connect($user, $pass, $sid);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect: " .  var_dump(OCIError()  );
    die();
}

}

$cmd="SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT EmpName, Used ArticleNo, Project  FROM Emp_PRJ_Art)
PIVOT(COUNT(ArticleNo) FOR (Project) IN ('PRJ1','PRJ2','PRJ3','PRJ4'))
ORDER BY Emp Name";
$stid = oci_parse($conn,$cmd); oci_execute($stid);
echo     "<tr>
            <th $backcol> $s Employee Name
            <th $backcol> $s Project-1
            <th $backcol> $s Project-2
            <th $backcol> $s Project-3
            <th $backcol> $s Project-4
            <th $backcol> $s EmpRol
             ";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td> $s " .$row['EmpName']
        ."<td> $s " .$row['PRJ1']
        ."<td> $s " .$row['PRJ2']
        ."<td> $s " .$row['PRJ3']
        ."<td> $s " .$row['PRJ4']
        ."<td> $s " .$row['EmpRol']
        ;
} 
echo "</table>\n";
echo "<br><font color='blue'>This is a test</font>";
exit;
?>
```

The EmpName has 700 entries and Project has 70 entries. UsedArticle can be more than 10k.

Comment: Show the PHP code. To post code, mark it with the mouse and use the `{ }` tool in the SO editor.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The tag says `Oracle`, but the question says `SQL-Server`

Comment: @Barmar, I am using Oracle SQL Developer Version 3.0.04. The database is ODBC. I am very new to this so not sure if I answered correctly.

Comment: Since you're having trouble when you try to run the query in PHP, you need to post the PHP code that's not working.

Comment: @Barmer I have posted the PHP code.

Comment: Some of your quotes are the wrong kind. They should be ASCII single quotes (`'`), not Unicode curly quotes (`’`). You're also missing the quote after `PRJ2`.

Comment: it's okay in Notepad++ !!! Corrected here too. What I am getting in the result is the Header of the table and nothing else. And of course a test message at the end of the script to see if it runs till end.

Comment: Check whether `oci_parse` and `oci_execute` are returning an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous errors in your code that stop it working correctly.  I've modified it as follows and tested it successfully against my setup (Oracle 11gR2, PHP 5.6.x).  Most important is aliasing the `IN` values so they aren't referenced with surrounding single quotes `'`.

```
<?php
$backcol = "bgcolor=#9fffa1"; // Light Green    
//$colgreen1 = "bgcolor=#5EE060"; // Light Green

//$maxitems = 1000; // Maximum items found to display

$s=" <small> ";

$user = 'odbc';
$pass = 'abcd';
$sid = 'server1.myComp.com';

//$adr = "http://server1/WebEditor";

$conn = oci_connect($user, $pass, $sid);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect: " .  var_dump(OCIError());
    die();
}

//}

$cmd = "SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT EmpName, UsedArticleNo, Project, EmpRol  FROM Emp_PRJ_Art)
PIVOT(COUNT(UsedArticleNo) FOR (Project) IN ('PRJ1' as prj1, 'PRJ2' as prj2, 'PRJ3' as prj3, 'PRJ4' as prj4))
ORDER BY EmpName";

$stid = oci_parse($conn,$cmd);
oci_execute($stid);

echo     "<table>
          <tr>
            <th $backcol> $s Employee Name </th>
            <th $backcol> $s Project-1 </th>
            <th $backcol> $s Project-2 </th>
            <th $backcol> $s Project-3 </th>
            <th $backcol> $s Project-4 </th>
            <th $backcol> $s EmpRol </th>
          </tr>";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td> $s " . $row['EN'] . "</td>"
        ."<td> $s " . $row['PRJ1'] . "</td>"
        ."<td> $s " . $row['PRJ2'] . "</td>"
        ."<td> $s " . $row['PRJ3'] . "</td>"
        ."<td> $s " . $row['PRJ4'] . "</td>"
        ."<td> $s " . $row['ER'] . "</td>"
        ."</tr>"
    ;
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Now I am getting the table with all employee name and EmpRol only. But nothing as the total number of UsedArticleNo by an Emp for a PRJ.  :(

Comment: Verify that the data is being returned and you have the correct key names in your `echo` statement by adding `var_dump($row);` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Bhaskar Any further response to this?

Comment: 'string(6) "Archie" ["EmpRol"]=> string(2) "PM" 
["prj1"]=> string(1) "0" ["prj2"]=> string(1) "0" ["prj3"]=> string(1) "0" ["prj4"]=> string(1) "2"}'  ...this is what I am getting from 'var_dump ($row)'.  don't understand then why there is blank in the table. I think I must get 2 under prj4 and 0 at other place.

Comment: Array keys are case-sensitive.  Your `var_dump()` shows them as mixed/lower case.  Double-check that your `echo` uses `$row['prj1']` and not `$row['PRJ1']`.

Comment: that means if I write ` IN ('PRJ1' as Proj1,` for query  , I must write   `."<td> $s " . $row['Proj1] . "</td>"` ?? I am checking all..

Comment: It's a little complicated because of the OCI behaviour.  OCI will normally convert all field names to upper case. So something like `select xyz...` will need to be referenced as `['XYZ']`.  `select xyz as abc...` will need to be referenced as `['ABC']`.  But `select xyz as 'abc'...` (note the apostrophes around the alias) will need to be referenced as `['abc']`.

Comment: that's it..my very limited knowledge spoiled them earlier. Thank you very much timclutton, for having patients to guide me.